# images not rendered over HTTPS URL while using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I am facing issue while convert HTML to PDF by using wkhtmltopdf.
Images over HTTPS URLs are not being converted and blank space is left in PDF document.

Is there any way to get root cause for it and fix it?

Comment: What type of image is it?  I think it has trouble with GIF images and also images with no extension.

Comment: @bUKaneer There are only .jpg or .png images over HTTPS urls.